# How to extend this sda6 partition from unallocated partition?

Tags: partitioning

[Link to Ubuntu File system partition Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vh2T.png)
I want to extend this Ubuntu sda6 partition from unallocated partition but i already have 4 primary partition and this Unallocated partition is from windows so i can't create partition and extend.How to extend this sda6 without losing data and Ubuntu OS.
I tried with Ubuntu G-pated but same message occurring.

Answer (score 0):

First, since you can't modify a currently mounted filesystem, you will need to use a Live CD.

Second, filesystems and partitions can only be extended to the right, not to the left. Since in your case the unallocated space is to the left of the partition you wish to extend, you will need to first move it to the left (so the unallocated space is moved to the right of the partition). **This operation is lengthy and risky**, so backup your data and grab a good book.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup before attempting any partition manipulation.

Gparted will only allow manipulating unmounted partitions.

Boot from a liveCD. The unallocated space needs to be added to the extended partition. Once the unallocated space is in the extended partition, then you can either make another logical partition or add it to an existing partition.

Note: moving boot files can cause boot errors. so try not to move your root partition.

My recommendation is to take a little more space from Windows so you have a total of 30-35GB unallocated space. Then, grow the extended partition (sda4) so that in includes the unallocated space. Then, grow sda5.
Use sda5 for storing personal data, or move your entire home folder to sda5.